# What is NSData or Data in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am pretty new to swift and i came across "Data" while programming in swift. i came across it while using UserDefaults in iOS. I read through the docs that Apple provided but couldn't understand much.

Can anyone please explain to me what it is?

```
static var _currentUser: User?

    class var currentUser: User? {
        get {
            if _currentUser == nil {
                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                let savedUser = defaults.object(forKey: "savedUser") as? Data
                if let savedUser = savedUser {
                    let dict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: savedUser as Data, options: [])
                    _currentUser = User(currentUserInfo: dict as! NSDictionary)
                }
            }
            return _currentUser
        }
        set(user){
            _currentUser = user
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            if let user = user {
                let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: (user.userInfo)!, options: [])
                defaults.set(data, forKey: "savedUser")
                print("current user saved")
            }
            else {
                defaults.removeObject(forKey: "savedUser")
            }
            defaults.synchronize()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Apple changed remove the `NS` prefix from Swift 3. So `NSData` became `Data`. In Swift 2 and older, `NS` anywhere. For example: `NSUserDefault`, `NSJSONSerialization`, `NSURL`,...

Comment: thanks, i got that part @DanhHuynh but what kind of object it really is?

Comment: @kennytm posted real code.

Comment: Data in Swift 3 is a struct that conforms to collection protocol. It is a collection of bytes (`[UInt8]` array of  unsigned integer 8 bits 0-255).

Comment: It's a class representing a collection of bytes. That's it. What else do you wish to know about it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Data and NSData are types used to interact with raw binary data. They’re commonly used to hold raw data more complex than single strings, integers, bools, and so on. Images for instance. Why raw? In order to write to and read from files, databases, memory, etc.

For example, on iOS, it’s widely used in data persistence frameworks like Core Data and Realm. Without Data, a data persistence framework would need hundreds of additional types to satisfy most use cases, which would be a sisyphean task to program and even worse, make the framework bloatware; with Data, the framework only has to persist that type and the developer is responsible for encoding and decoding it, allowing for all possible use cases.

Answer (score 6):

The NS prefix it's from the [NeXTSTEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeXTSTEP) heritage. NeXT was a computer company that Steve Jobs formed after he was fired by Apple.

Apple removed the NS prefix with the release of Swift 3.

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata):

> NSData and its mutable subclass NSMutable​Data provide data objects, object-oriented wrappers for byte buffers. Data objects let simple allocated buffers (that is, data with no embedded pointers) take on the behavior of Foundation objects.
>
> NSData creates static data objects, and NSMutable​Data creates dynamic data objects. NSData and NSMutable​Data are typically used for data storage and are also useful in Distributed Objects applications, where data contained in data objects can be copied or moved between applications.